# Running h2 in MODE=MySQL doesn't support MySQL dumps

Tags: java, mysql, integration-testing, h2, embedded-database

I'm trying to embed h2 to test my mysql-application (integration-test)

I added com.h2database:h2:1.3.170 via maven and run the following code:

```
public class InMemoryTest
{
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
      Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

      Connection conn = DriverManager.
          getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'src/test/resources/test.sql'");
    }
}
```

which gives me the following Exception:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ""usr_avatar"" (
  ""usr_avatar_id"" INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ""usr_avatar_user_id"" INT(11) NOT NULL,
  ""usr_avatar_img"" BLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (""usr_avatar_id""),
  UNIQUE KEY ""usr_avatar_id_UNIQUE"" (""usr_avatar_id""),
  UNIQUE KEY ""usr_avatar_user_id_UNIQUE"" (""usr_avatar_user_id""),
  KEY ""usr_user_id"" (""usr_avatar_user_id""),
  KEY ""fk_user_id"" (""usr_avatar_user_id"")
) AUTO_INCREMENT[*]=1  ";
```

Apparently, the "AUTO_INCREMENT" causes this?

Since this is valid MySQL (I exported the dump from my real database using MySQL Workbench), I'm a bit confused since h2 claims to support MySQL?
Here are a few lines from the .sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usr_avatar`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "usr_avatar" (
  "usr_avatar_id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "usr_avatar_user_id" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "usr_avatar_img" blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("usr_avatar_id"),
  UNIQUE KEY "usr_avatar_id_UNIQUE" ("usr_avatar_id"),
  UNIQUE KEY "usr_avatar_user_id_UNIQUE" ("usr_avatar_user_id"),
  KEY "usr_user_id" ("usr_avatar_user_id"),
  KEY "fk_user_id" ("usr_avatar_user_id")
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usr_restriction`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "usr_restriction" (
  "usr_restriction_id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "usr_restriction_user_id" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  "usr_restriction_ip" varchar(39) DEFAULT NULL,
  "usr_restriction_valid_from" date NOT NULL,
  "usr_restriction_valid_to" date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("usr_restriction_id"),
  UNIQUE KEY "usr_restriction_id_UNIQUE" ("usr_restriction_id"),
  KEY "user_id" ("usr_restriction_user_id"),
  KEY "usr_user_id" ("usr_restriction_user_id")
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

What are my options? Should I export the dump with a different software and force it to be plain SQL? Which software could do that? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source SQL exported from MySQL has double-quotes surrounding it's literals.  The first DROP statement also has a "back-tick" (`).  But when H2 is reporting the error, H2 is showing the literals surrounded by double-double quotes.  I think this is the problem.

Try a couple of things.  First, take the back-tick in the DROP statement and convert it to single quotes.  If that doesn't work, convert all of the double-quotes to single-quotes.  If that doesn't work, remove all of the quotes.

I think H2 is trying to create tables with the double-quotes as a part of the actual table names/column names and this is causing it to bomb.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - backticking or removing quotes/ticks from table-names worked fine, while single/double-quotes caused problems.
Nevertheless, there is still a problem with the "AUTO_INCREMENT=1;" at the end of my table.
But since itt turns out that h2 always starts with value 1 anyways, this is not needed.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it worked.  It honestly doesn't surprise me that the AUTO_INCREMENT modifier didn't work.  I don't think H2 has an exact one-for-one implementation for MySQL-specific behavior.  But H2 does have the ability to ALTER SEQUENCE which you can look into if you need it.

Comment: Thanks! Talking about ALTER'ing things .. 
When adding constraints, it's only possible to add one at a time. So "ALTER TABLE `a` ADD CONSTRAINT ... ; ALTER TABLE `a`..."

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that H2 doesn't support `AUTO_INCREMENT=1`, which you have specified in the SQL statement. Try removing it. I don't think it's necessary for MySQL either.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for letting us have a definite answer! As I said before, obviously h2 starts with 1 by default. Maybe it's worth mentioning on your page which quotes (apparently back-tick or no quotes at all) should be used, and that it's only possibly to add one contraint at a time. Thank you very much for all the time and effort you've put into h2 - this database is definitely my choice when it comes to integration-testing in-memory ;-)

Comment: Double quotes and back-ticks are not the problem: they are supported by H2. The position in the SQL statement where the error occurs is actually marked with a `[*]`: the error message as `... AUTO_INCREMENT[*]=1 ...`

Answer (score 2):

H2 doesn't support `AUTO_INCREMENT=1`.

Use this instead:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 1;
```